# JavaScript - Python communication in iOS using Instruments

Tags: javascript, python, ios, xcode5, ios-ui-automation

I would like to exchange messsages between `Javascript` and `Pythonscript` in iPhone Application,which does not involve any Web. I am using UIAutomation framework in the iPhone app.Is there any api to communicate from `Javascript` to `Python`?

Can I use the following ?

https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

In the following link it is specified it is for browser.

[JavaScript/JQuery communicate with SerialPort/COM1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379529/javascript-jquery-communicate-with-serialport-com1)

I have requirement where I need to invoke `Javascript` from `Python`.

In `Android` this is possible using `adb commands`.How to do the similar thing in `iOS` app using `UIAutomation` or someother framework which uses `Javascipt`.

I am able to execute `pythonscript`on Mac from `iOS` app (`UIAutomation` framework) using the following Code.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/python",["~/Sample.py"],10);
```

Is there any way to send some messages using `pythonscript` on Mac (host) to `iOS` app (which uses`UIAutomation` framework.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've seen you'll have to poll from your UIAutomation script. There isn't a built in interrupt service. I've been working on a way to do this and what I've come up with is writing all my scripts inside of a string and then using eval and an execution loop so that I can perform polling between every line of my UIAutomation script. There might be a better way to do it though! The software itself has a very narrow scope and so it's difficult to push the boundaries.